# how to implement a google map in a stack with two inputs on top of the map

Tags: flutter

When i place a google map in a stack it doesn't appear.When i place it in a sized box inside a column it works.I want the map in a stack.

The code below is the implementation of the map in a stack but it doesn't work,I need help (The Error is  _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding&ServicesBinding&SchedulerBinding&PaintingBinding&SemanticsBinding&RendererBinding.drawFrame
This RenderObject has no descendants.
 Another exception was thrown: RenderAndroidView object was given an infinite size during layout.
 Another exception was thrown: RenderFlex object was given an infinite size during layout.)

```
Stack(
              children: <Widget>[
                GoogleMap(
                  initialCameraPosition: CameraPosition(
                      target: _center,
                      zoom: 11.0
                  ),
                  onMapCreated: _onMapCreated,
                )
              ],
            )
```

The code below works fine.How can i implement the above code below and have the map working fine

```
  body:SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[

          Column(
               crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
               children: inputs(),
          ),
            SizedBox(
              height:500,
              child:  GoogleMap(
                initialCameraPosition: CameraPosition(
                    target: _center,
                    zoom: 11.0
                ),
                onMapCreated: _onMapCreated,
              ),
            ),

          ],
        )
      ),
```

Comment: Since it's in the SingleChildScrollView, your GoogleMap widget trying to get the any available size and it goes to the infinity.

Answer (score 0):

Your widget size needs to be constrained in this case and you actually solve it by wrapping with SizedBox. Can't you wrap your SizedBox to a Stack?

Answer (score 0):

I used Positioned.fill() to position the map and positioned() for other widgets in the stack.It worked fine